# How to automatically play videos when they enter the viewport with html / js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a scrollable website the shows several videos. some of these videos start outside the viewport. when the user scrolls the viewport so that one of these videos enters the viewport I would like for the video to start playing with no further input from the user. If possible I would also like the video to stop playing once it exits the viewport. how might I do this? I can get it to the point where if the user clicks play it will then follow these rules but I would like for the  whole process to be hands off. Thanks for any help.

This is what I tried:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #video {
                margin-top: 1500px;
                margin-bottom: 1000px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <video id="video" src="video_ex.mp4"></video>

        <script>
            let options = {
                root: null,
                rootMargin: '0px',
                threshold: 1.0
            };
            let callback = (entries, observer) => {
                entries.forEach(entry => {
                    if (entry.target.id == "video") {
                        if (entry.isIntersecting){
                            entry.target.play();
                        }
                        else {
                            entry.target.pause
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
            observer.observe(document.querySelector('#video'))

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't, because browsers don't allow autoplay until _after_ the user has interacted with the page. Because the last thing your page should be allowed to do is start playing a loud, inappropriate video unprompted.

Comment: You can do that if you add `muted` attribute

Comment: You missed parenthesis `entry.target.pause()`